# Android Studio 3.0 is stuck loading symbols for my project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I updated from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.0 . Now my project is stuck loading symbols for more than 30 mins. Any pointers on how to resolve this?

I tried to reinstall it - the same result.

I tried to relaunch - the same result.

Comment: Have you try renaming/removing `.gradle` directory inside your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project,

1. Delete `{root}/.gradle` folder
2. Delete `{root}/app/build` folder
3. Delete `{root}/build` folder
4. Run `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
5. Sync your project again after Android Studio restarts

Comment: @DemetrioGuilardi are you still facing the same problem?

Comment: yes! I think I know what it is, dumb android studio indexes all my files, including downloads, songs or whatever file I have in my hard drive. I will try moving all these docs to another computer.

Comment: What is the installation location of Android Studio on your PC?

Comment: I found a solution, please see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION FOUND!!!**

Android Studio does the most dumb thing: it indexes ALL FILES on your PC.
Straight to the point: I deleted my downloads and DerivedData folder and all went alright.

A short explanation.
. DerivedData became a huge folder with tons of files making Android Studio loop forever on those files
. On my Mac the Downloads folder is shared as hard links with multiple apps. for example, the Skype or Steam apps have hard links to the Download folder, making Android Studio re index the entire Downloads folder multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me as a Windows user was to close android studio via Task Manager and navigate to my

> C:/ drive -> Users -> My user profile

- I then deleted the **.android** file and re-opened android studio again.
- Opened AppData in that same directly which revealed the directories i) Local ii)LocalLow iii)Roaming
- Opening Local I deleted the Android Directory in there
- Opened the Google Directory i.e. AppData -> Local -> Google and deleted the directory AndroidStudio2021.2
- Navigated to AppData -> Roaming and deleted the Google Directory in there.
- I then opened Android Studio again.

P.S: I lost all my plugins installed and any other customizations but it worked.